# Is it possible to omit things in the class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm writing documentation for a school java project I'm working on. Basically have chunked most of the methods into the class diagram, but now it seems very unreadable on a pdf as the words are too small. I want to ask for feedback on this issue, as well as other things my class diagram is missing. Thanks.

[image: Class Diagram]

Comment: In the real world, yes, in the school world - ask your teacher.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Alright noted, is there any other things missing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer depends on the expectation of the teacher. This is essentially a homework challenge and OP's situation doesn't necessarily follow suit with whatever is customary in a professional context.

Comment: Assuming (1) that this is just for documentation, not code generation, and (2) that your teacher doesn't object, one thing you can do is just display class names in the overall diagram to show the structure (so, just a box with a name; but maybe leave the interface as is, as this is the main abstraction); alternatively, omit anything that's not public. Then if necessary, show the full version of individual classes separately on the following pages. P.S. The type of the properties/fields (member vars) normally goes to the right of the name (same as for function return type).

Comment: The above would be more fitting on a page with landscape orientation, wider than high. Also check the use of using an export format with vector graphics, SVG or EPS, so the reader can zoom in to 200% allowing you to use tiny text for fields.

Answer (score 4):

UML is unified modeling language. UML is used by different people for different need. [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/) did quite some work in UML, and he says there are different [modes of using UML](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlMode.html). The modes of UML are

**1. UML as a sketch:** (YES) In this mode we use UML to express an aspect of the system. In this mode what ever information is not needed for communicating the aspect it could be omitted. Else it would clutter the diagram like in your case

**2. UML as a blue print:** (NO) This mode is used when the software is designed by one group (expensive group) and the design is communicated to another group (less expensive group) of developers to implement. It wouldn't make sense in this mode to skip details.

**3. UML as Programming Language:** (NO) In this mode UML is considered as a higher level. So the intention is generate code from UML. It wouldn't make sense to skip details in this mode as well.

So depending on how you use UML, you could decide to skip details or not.

Comment: "2. UML as a blue print: [...] It wouldn't make sense in this mode to skip details" - I don't know about that ... those devs in the other group are almost certainly not going to follow that ivory tower design to the letter anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to have one single UML diagram. *Unless teacher says so.* You can represent everything in UML, just in multiple diagrams. For example, you can represent a class in full implementation -level detail in a diagram, and have details suppressed (that is only the name of the class in a box) in other diagrams.

You might, for example, decide to break a big diagram into smaller parts, just showing the connections to detail suppressed classes so we know how the diagrams connects... or you can decide to have one big diagram showing all the relationships but all classes have details suppressed, and then a diagram per class showing all the details you have.

And yes, you can show different details of a class in different diagrams, and that would mean the class all the details from all the diagrams. This is particularly useful if you are sketching a design or doing analysis over a part of the system. However, if you are supposed to present a full design, remember that flipping over multiple diagrams to figure out the full details of a class does not make for a great reading experience.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends *entirely* on the needs of the person for whom you are generating the diagrams. If they need the detail, then the detail must remain. If not, you can omit the things they don't need.